# Problema para gerar tabela de confrontos

Tags: php

Estou em um projeto, cujo eu preciso gerar uma tabela de um campeonato de futebol, onde todos joguem contra todos, porém quando eu gero até 4 times, as rodas são geradas perfeitamente, quando eu gero 10 times por exemplo, começa a dar problema nas rodas.

[Link do script no Ideone](http://ideone.com/dt4hT1).

```
$times = array('Time1','Time2','Time3','Time4','Time5','Time6','Time7','Time8','Time9','Time10'); //Array de Times
$qtde_times = count($times); // Quantidade de Times
$num_rodadas = $qtde_times - 1; //numero de rodadas
$times_por_rodada = 2 * (int) ($qtde_times / 2);
$casa = array(); //guarda os jogos de quem joga em casa
$fora = array(); // guarda os jogos de quem joga fora
$jogos = array(); // guarda os jogos no final
$jogos_temp = array(); //array temporário, verifica quem já jogou em cada rodada
for ($i = 0; $i < $qtde_times; $i++) { //For para caminhar entre os times
    for ($j = $i; $j < $qtde_times; $j++) { //For para caminha entre os adversários
        if ($times[$i] != $times[$j]) { //verifica pra não deixar jogar um time contra ele mesmo
            if ($j % 2 == 0) { //if pra ver quem joga em casa ou fora
                $casa[] = $times[$i];
                $fora[] = $times[$j];
            } else {
                $casa[] = $times[$j];
                $fora[] = $times[$i];
            }//fim do if / else de jogar em casa ou fora
        }// verifica se é diferente pra poder fazer o confronto
    }// fim do for que caminha entre os adversários
}// fim do for que verifica os times

//parte que verifica quem já jogou em qual rodada
for ($rodada = 0; $rodada < $num_rodadas; $rodada++) {
    for ($t = 0; $t < count($casa); $t++) {
        if (($casa[$t] != "") and ((in_array($casa[$t], $jogos_temp)) == false) and (((in_array($fora[$t], $jogos_temp)) == false))) {
            $jogos_temp[] = $casa[$t];
            $jogos_temp[] = $fora[$t];
            $casa[$t] = "";
            $fora[$t] = "";
        }
    }
    $jogos["Rodada: " . ($rodada + 1)] = $jogos_temp;
    $jogos_temp = array();
}

for ($rod = 0; $rod < $num_rodadas; $rod++) {
    echo "Rodada: " . ($rod + 1) . "<br />";
    for ($jog = 0; $jog < $times_por_rodada; $jog+=2) {
        echo $jogos["Rodada: " . ($rod + 1)][$jog] . " x " . $jogos["Rodada: " . ($rod + 1)][($jog + 1)] . "<br />";
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Alguém saberia me dizer o que posso estar fazendo para resolver isso?

Comment: Amigo, a ideia do fórum é que tudo possa ser reaproveitado por outras pessoas, por este motivo você deve postar o seu código aqui, pois caso o link se perca, a pergunta não será inutilizada...

Comment: Eu não postei foi por que eu não consegui,todas as maneiras que eu postava,o código ficava bugado.

Você pode me auxiliar para resolver o problema?

Obrigado!

Comment: Editei para você!